# Macro that knows void * allocation type

Tags: c, macros, metaprogramming

Let have this code as example:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    char another;
} foo;

typedef struct {
    float yet_another;
    long really_another;
} bar;

typedef struct {
    char* name;
    void* data;
} gen;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    gen foo_gen, bar_gen;

    foo_gen.name = "Foo";
    foo_gen.data = (foo*) malloc(sizeof(foo));

    bar_gen.name = "Bar";
    bar_gen.data = (bar*) malloc(sizeof(bar));

    ((foo*) foo_gen->data)->value = 0;
    ((bar*) bar_gen->data)->yet_another = 1.0f;

    return 0;
}
```

This code would work ok, so I defined 2 macro to facilitate my work:

```
#define FOO_DATA(N, D) ((foo*) N->data)->D
#define BAR_DATA(N, D) ((bar*) N->data)->D
```

But it seems to be too repetitive. I want it to make more generic, making the macro to know which type it should cast. I tried using `__auto_type`:

```
#define DATA(N, D) (__auto_type N->data)->D
```

But it didn't work. It seems too that `typeof` don't works with macros. How should I do it?

Comment: What are you casting it from, and what determines what you cast it to?

Comment: Where is the macro supposed to get the information for what type `data_s` should be?

Comment: Please note that this is an anti-pattern. In c, you are not supposed to infer the type of a variable. Instead, you should try some of the well known techniques to do what is like generic types, but is not. You can 1. Use a union, 2. Use `void *` pointers. Also, your macro is completely unclear, because `self->data` should be 1. Non-NULL and 2. Declared somewhere else, so the macro doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It seems to me, especially from how you tried to use `typeof`, that either `self->data` already has the right type and casting is unnecessary, or you don't know what the right type is and you're expecting the macro to somehow come up with information you don't have.

Comment: Also, if these structures have common fields, there is a trick you can use to immitate inheritance, just define the common fields in a macro and add them to every derived structure. You will then be safe to use the common fields casting to the structure that has only the common fields, since the memory layout will be the same in principle.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi The macro is discontextualized here. I have a struct which has a property called data, which is a pointer void. The idea is to have a struct in the data field, but this struct could be anything. For example, I could make a struct with a `int value` field, and then call the macro with $(value). It works if I specify the data struct name, but the intention is to make the macro generic, so as any struct should work.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi `data` is a `void *` common field, but `data` should be a struct which fields are not common.

Comment: @MateusFelipe: That’s impossible. A field named “foo” could be at the start of one struct and at the end of another. There’s certainly no way for the preprocessor to know which to use. If you have fields that are common between all the structs, you can create a struct that contains them and make a field of that type the first field of all the “derived” structs. (edit: still not a good idea because it violates strict aliasing.) (edit2: no, it’s actually fine, I’m not thinking straight.)

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: That actually violates strict aliasing. There are some exceptions involving unions, but in the absence of such a union, you can't do that.

Comment: @user2357112 Indeed, I want macro to know `self->data` type, as it's a `void *` and thus data type may vary.

Comment: @MateusFelipe It's a `void *` and thus data type is `void *`. It can't vary.

Comment: @immibis Indeed, but I think you got what I meant. I could initialize this variable with any struct. For example, `structure->data = (data_s*) malloc(sizeof(data_s));` or `structure->data = (another_s*) malloc(sizeof(another_s));`. So, when I have to access the struct I cast the type again: `((data_s*) self->data)` or `((another_s*) self->data)`. I wanna the macro to know to which type cast.

Comment: @MateusFelipe `structure->data (data_s*)mallo(sizeof(data_s));` and `structure->data = (another_s*)malloc(sizeof(another_s));` **are identical** if the structures happen to have the same size and if `structure->data` has type `void*`. That means there's no way to distinguish between them because they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @immibis If the two structs are different, they are not identical, and macro won't work.

Comment: @MateusFelipe No, I was saying the allocation is identical for two structs that have the same size. (Did you read the comment?)

Comment: @immibis They are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @immibis It doesn't matter if the allocation is identic, as I won't be able to cast it properly.

Comment: Edited the question trying to make it clearer.

Comment: What you’re looking for in your edit can’t be done. Keep casting manually.

Comment: @MateusFelipe You suggested the computer should know how to cast it based on how you allocated it. I'm saying the computer doesn't know how you allocated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If me and the other commenters understand correctly, you want to be able to do something like this:

```
struct a {
    int field1;
} a;

struct b {
    int field2;
} b;

void *self1 = &a;
void *self2 = &b;

int f1 = MAGIC(self1)->field1;
int f2 = MAGIC(self2)->field2;
```

for some definition of `MAGIC`.

This is not possible in C.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment: you would have to group your common fields into another struct and make that the first field of the possible structs in `self->data`:

```
struct common {
    int foo;
};

struct a {
    struct common common;
    int bar;
};

struct b {
    struct common common;
    int baz;
};

#define $(D) (((struct common*) self->data)->D)
```